# how to refresh and rebind the data from db in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

hi all iam using angularjs ngrepeat to bind the datas into table.i have one add new button when i click bootstrap model popup open i fill the input details click submit means data will stored correctly but table couldn't not get the new data but once i reload the page data will show

### my controller code

```
var refresh = function () {
        $http.get('/ViewFacility').success(function (response) {
            $scope.ViewFacilitys = response;


    };

    refresh();
```

### My add new code:

```
$scope.AddRole = function () {

        $http.post('/AddNewRole', $scope.Role).success(function (response) {

            refresh();
        });
    };
```

### Html Code

```
  <form name="profileform">
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" ng-controller="IndexController">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content" style="margin-top:135px">
                        <div class="modal-header">

                            <h4 class="modal-title ">Role Name</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <h4>Name</h4>
                            <input type="text" name="RoleName" class="form-control" ng-model="Role.RoleName">
                            <span class="error" ng-show="profileform.FirstName.$invalid && profileform.FirstName.$dirty">Please enter a First Name</span>

                            <h4>Description</h4>
                            <input type="text" name="Description" class="form-control" ng-model="Role.Description">
                            <span class="error" ng-show="profileform.LastName.$invalid && profileform.LastName.$dirty">Please enter a Last Name</span>

                            <h4>IsActive</h4>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="IsActive" class="form-control checkbox" ng-model="Role.IsActive" style="margin-left:-47%" >
                            <span class="error" ng-show="profileform.Email.$invalid && profileform.Email.$dirty">Please enter a Email</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="AddRole()" ng-disabled="profileform.$invalid">Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="deselect()">Clear</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the html codes? And pls check the result of the addRole function is the response successfull or not?

Comment: sure @UtkuApaydin responce are successfull and data also stored in db(I am using Mongodb)

Comment: Hİa gain i asked for your grid html how do you bind it to your response to html is the controller still seeing the scope of that dom element. Those are the questions that you have to check.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the new item to the array.

```
$scope.AddRole = function () {
    $http.post('/AddNewRole', $scope.Role).success(function (response) {
       $scope.ViewFacilitys.push($scope.Role);
    });
};
```

You don't need to fetch all data each time you create a new item. Refresh must be called just one time.

For pagination you can code a simple function that send the number of page to the server:

```
$scope.changePage = function (page) {
    $scope.get('/ViewFacility?page='+page)
       .then(function (response) {
          $scope.ViewFacilitys = response.data;
       });
}
```

Comment: it's won't work @carlos still same after reload the page data will come

Comment: @jose, carlos' point here is `reload` should only be called once(eg. page init) to refrain from unnecessary api calls (unless theres data generated for every record in your controller)

Comment: @barak iam not able to reload the page but i want bind the data any solution

Comment: @jose you wrote "iam using angularjs ngrepeat to bind the datas into table", so if you add or remove some element from your array that is used in ng-repeat, the table automatically will be updated

Comment: @CarlosArauz i apologize for that but i need pagination also any solution help

Comment: I recommend you to use a plugin like angular-datatables, but for simple pagination you can just send to the server the number of page, take a look the new code

Comment: any angular pugin datatable link or sample @CarlosArauz

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `refresh` function like so

```
var refresh = function () {
        $http.get('/ViewFacility').success(function (response) { //assuming this only fetches the newly added one
            $scope.ViewFacilitys.push(response);
    };
```

Comment: $scope.ViewFacilitys.push(response); this function data also not bind in table yar

Comment: this entry form is one popup @barak

Comment: refer the imge may entry form is look like this@barak

Comment: @jose, please show the code where `ViewFacilitys` is being used (ng-repeat="facility in ViewFacilitys") something that looks like that

Comment: yes same its look like that
   <tr dir-paginate="Manage_Facility in ViewFacilitys |itemsPerPage:5| filter:search | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort " ng-class-odd="'odd'">

Comment: i am using pagination

Comment: then either something may be wrong with your `dir-paginate` directive or it doesnt implement two-way binding. Try removing pagination first, and replace it with `ng-repeat`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138289/discussion-between-barak-and-jose).